# Paginación Sequelize.query

Tags: nodejs, sequelize

Actualmente estoy usando una función de Sequelize llamada findAndCountAll, esto para realizar un paginado y funciona correctamente, pero la necesidad que tengo es hacer un mismo paginado pero con una consulta definida. Leyendo la documentación de Sequelize, encontré que hay una función que se llama "query" en la cual se puede definir una consulta literal y pasarla para poder ejecutarla pero no he encontrado como hacer el paginado o si es posible.

Saben si hay alguna forma para poder ejecutar una consulta literal con Sequelize y que permita hacer el paginado que se requiere?

Anexo parte del código de como lo estaba trabajando:

```
sequelize.findAndCountAll({
    where: where,
    include: [{
        model: sucursalesModelo, as: 'Sucursal', required: true
    }],
    offset: offset, limit: limit
}).then(exito, error);
```

Lo que requiero es algo como lo siguiente (puede estar sujeto a cambios)

```
sequelize.query('CALL PagoSP( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL )',
    {
        offset: offset, limit: limit
    }
).then(exito, error);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sequelize.query(`CALL PagoSP( NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) LIMIT ${limit} OFFSET ${offset}`;
```

Comment: Explica un poco la corrección y por que, para que se pueda considerar una respuesta.